# switching between graphic cards in radeon open source driver

Tags: 14.04, ati, radeon, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity in my laptop with (AMD hd8760/Intel) dual graphics. **Fglrx is not working so I am using open source radeon driver. I know how to switch between cards when using fglrx.**

```
aticonfig --pxl # List current activated GPU
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu # Activate discrete GPU (High-Performance),re-start X to effect.
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu # Activate integrated GPU (Power-Saving),re-start X to effect.
```

1.When does the driver(opensource one) use radeon graphic card?

2.**How do I do the switching now(opensource driver)?**

3.**Do i have any application to do this(like catalyst in case of fglrx).**

4.How do I check whether DPM is enabled in radeon?